# How can I escape string css in sass/scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have a string that contain a css value and I want to use it but with gruntjs return me an error

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "   @media ": expected media query (e.g. print, screen, print and screen), was "$from-smartphon..."
```

this is my var

```
$from-smartphone-portrait:         "only screen and (min-width: 1px)";
```

and this is how I call it:

```
    @media $from-smartphone-portrait {
        // Smartphone portrait
        body {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 14px;
        }
    }
```

in LESS I can escape it in this mode:

```
@from-smartphone-portrait:         ~"only screen and (min-width: 1px)";
```

How can I make the same thing in SASS/SCSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can make use of the `unquote` function:

```
$from-smartphone-portrait: unquote("only screen and (min-width: 1px)");
```

To use the variable for the media query definition:

```
@media #{$from-smartphone-portrait} {
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with an update of the call of the `$from-smartphone-portrait` variable. Notice that this works as from Sass version 3.2

Comment: it works fine without using unquote is necessary this function?

Comment: Looking at the docs of SASS, it is not necessary to unquote first for media full query variables.