# How to force the Sass interpreter to output non-css code?

Tags: css, sass

I need to include some non-css interpreter instructions in a css file (these will be substituted later by another parser at runtime to create valid css).

The file is written in scss, so I use ruby/node sass to compile the file. During this process, I want it to leave the interpreter instructions untouched, i.e. they should be simply treated as literals and outputted. The instructions contain symbols that are not valid in css, so the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935792/how-can-i-escape-string-css-in-sass-scss) doesn't work for me.

What works fine is when the variable containing the insruction is referenced in a property value, so e.g. this compiles successfully:

```
$x: unquote("<<macro 'val1'>>");

a {
  b: $x; // compiles into:  b: <<macro 'val1'>>
}
```

This fails:

```
$x: unquote("<<macro 'val1'>>");

@media (max-width: #{$x}) { // throws an invalid css error
  .tc-sidebar-scrollable {
    .tmap-desktop-editor {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

In both cases, the output will not be valid css but in case of the media query, it completely fails. My Sass version is 3.4.13 (Selective Steve).

How can I get this to work? The resulting file should look like:

```
@media (max-width: <<macro 'val1'>>) {
  .tc-sidebar-scrollable .tmap-desktop-editor {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I made some search, and didn't find any solution to handle this. Can't you inverse the process (running you other parser first) ?

Comment: @ByScripts Sadly, this is not possible because the instructions (<<macro …>>) are substituted later dynamically by javascript at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a [cross post](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1957) at the sass GitHub repo and [was told](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1957#issuecomment-169402347) that interpolation happens before the media query is parsed, which is why it doesn't work here.

A possible (but still unsatisfying) workaround that [came up in the issue discussion](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1957#issuecomment-169406286) was to use custom at-rules to "get around Sass' proprietary handling of @media". So you would write e.g.

```
@_media (max-width: #{$x})
```

and after sass compiled you run a replace script that transforms `@_media` into `@media`.

Another similar idea was to use a css-valid placeholder for the non-valid css itself and later replace it in a second run after sass finished with the desired string…