# SASS is using math to divide my grid-column value

Tags: css, sass

So I'm trying to set a value on my `grid-column` in SCSS, like this:

```
grid-column: 1 / 3;
```

However when my SASS is compiled into CSS, it's thinking that's trying to do math and it's dividing that and outputting:

```
grid-column: 0.333333333;
```

How can I let SASS know I'm not trying to do math here?

Comment: Have you tried `/#` or `#{'/'}` instead of `/`?

Comment: you just need to escape it, I don't know the syntax in SCSS but in LESS it is `~"stuff to be left alone"` here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935792/how-can-i-escape-string-css-in-sass-scss/20935853